# Integration by parts with arcsin

Tags: integration

$$\int arcsin(x)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}dx$$
I noticed that $$\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$$ is similar to the derivation of arcsinx. Is there something I can do with this piece of information?
I cant just do integration by parts the way it is. What can do from here?

Comment: Definitely set $\arcsin x=y$

Comment: you mean switching the subject of the integral to arcsin?

Comment: @yinonelirazis it arcsin $(sqrt 1 - x^{2} $

Comment: the $$arcsin$$ only applies to $$x$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try with the substitution $x=\sin t$. After a while use $\cos^2 t=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos (2t))$ and in the end $per-partes$.

Comment: you mean integration by parts or partial integration?